# Where does the Raspberry PI 3 b+ IO peripherals mapped in the ARM virtual address space?

Tags: linux, pi-3b+

[BCM2835 data sheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf)
The earlier version of Raspberry PI (BCM 2835) data sheet shows that the IO Peripherals are mapped from starting address -

0x20000000 - In ARM physical address space

0xF2000000 - In Kernel virtual address space

I am aware that the Raspberry PI 3B+ (BCM 2837) and also BCM 2836 is mostly similar to BCM 2835 and that is the reason there is no separate data sheet available for both 2836 and 2837. There is a difference in the memory map on the Raspberry PI3 B+, The IO peripherals are mapped from starting address 0x3F000000 instead of 0x20000000 in ARM physical address space.

I am not sure if the kernel virtual address map in RPI 3b+ is still same as the previous version i.e starting at address 0xF2000000, or it is mapped to a different location ?

Please help me to understand this.